# Convert my existing Node Js code into Async Await

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am New To async/await coding in node js. I am trying to fetch data from mysql and then populate the result into an object. But i am not finding a way how to do it in **controller.js** file.
My source code similar to [this](https://bezkoder.com/node-js-rest-api-express-mysql/).

1. **My Router File**

```
const express = require("express");
const controller = require("controller");
const router = express.Router();
router.route("/").get(controller.findAll);
```

2. **My Controller File**

```
const model = require("model");
exports.findAll = async (req, res) => {
   
    const all = model.getAll((err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving data.",
            });
        }
        return data;
    });
    const user = model1.getUser((err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving user.",
            });
        }
        return data;
    });
    // somefunctionality(all, user);
    // res.send(result);
};
```

3. **My Model file**

```
const con = require("./db");

// constructor
const Customers= function (customer) {
    this.id = customer.id;
    this.first_name = customer.first_name;
    this.last_name = customer.last_name;
    this.email = customer.email;
};
Customers.getAll = () => {
    const query = `SELECT * FROM doctors`;
    sql.query(query, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log("error: ", err);
          result(null, err);
          return;
    }
    console.log("customers: ", res);
    result(null, res);
};
```

> user model same as customer

*Thanks for your help*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Comment: Could you share which npm package is the sql function

Comment: I used [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)     package for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do is covert your `Customers.getAll` method to return a promise:

**model file**

```js
Customers.getAll = () => {
  const query = `SELECT * FROM doctors`;
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    sql.query(query, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error: ", err);
        rej(err);
        return;
      }
    console.log("customers: ", res);
    res(data);
  })
};
```

(Note that you'll probably have to do something similar to the `getAll` method for your `User` model)

Now, in the controller, you can use `try/catch` to handle any errors.

**controller file*

```js
exports.findAll = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const all = await model.getAll();
    const users = await model1.getUser();
    const result = somefunctionality(all, user);
    res.send(result);
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving data.",
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks Nick for your help. but i was trying to do  like only useing async and await keyword.

Comment: So that depends a bit on whether the `sql` package has promises built-in. Otherwise, you're going to _have_ to convert any callbacks to Promises because async await _is_ just promises under the hood.